# Add floating point numbers 23.54 and 33.22 with just integral value like 23+33

Tags: c, floating-point

There are two floating point numbers 23.54 and 33.22 have to make a program to add them with just left side integral value like 23+33=56.

Here's the code that I tried:

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: Please post code as `formatted text`, not screenshots

Comment: sorry bro i'm new to this website and programming that's why i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sum;
sum=(int)num1+(int)num2;
printf("%d",sum);
```

**or**

```
printf("%d",(int)num1+(int)num2);
```

The datatype of num1 is float and I'm using (int) to typecast to integer type.
Since we typecast the datatype this is called explicit typecasting!

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing services; it is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers so that it provides knowledge.

Comment: Should I need to elaborate more @EricPostpischil?

Comment: Think about what somebody needs to know to understand why this works. What does a cast do? What does “typecast to integer type” mean? If you have 23.54 and you “cast” (what does that word mean?) it to an “integer type”, what do you get? 23.54 is not an integer, so how do you make it an integer type?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to define a function that explicitly names the types used, for example:

```
static int int_sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

which could be used as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a, b;
    if (scanf("%f%f", &a, &b) == 2) {
        printf("%d\n", int_sum(a, b));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

note that it's good practice to check that `scanf` successfully parsed the values it was supposed to before using them.  You might instead want to return something else, or maybe print an error message, if the user didn't supply valid input.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){



float sum;
float num1;  
float num2;
printf("first number:");
scanf("%f",&num1);
printf("second number:");
scanf("%f",&num2);
sum=(int)num1+int(num2);
printf("sum is %.2f",sum);
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing services; it is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers so that it provides knowledge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).